# Scala max value of the queue made with 2 lists with O(1) complexity

Tags: scala, templates, queue, time-complexity, max

I have such queue structure.

```
class Queue[A] private (in: List[A], out: List[A]) {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = in.isEmpty && out.isEmpty
    
  def enqueue(elem: A): Queue[A] = new Queue(elem :: in, out)
    
  def dequeue(): (A, Queue[A]) = 
    out match {
      case head :: tail => (head, new Queue(in, tail))
      case Nil =>
        val head :: tail = in.reverse  // throws exception if empty
        (head, new Queue(Nil, tail))
    }
}
```

I want to add `extractMax()` method with O(1) complexity that returns max value element of queue if `A` is an Integer type.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't. O(1) is impossible, because no matter how clever the order is in which you look at the numbers, the next number can always be larger, and you can't make sure that you didn't miss the largest number until you looked at all O(N) of them.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, that's not totally correct.  One could implement a collection which exposes `enqueue`/`dequeue`/`peek`/`isEmpty` (thus satisfies the `Queue` API) and has an `extractMax` which is O(1); the downside is that `dequeue`/`peek` would then have to have O(n) complexity (which kind of makes it a very poor `Queue`).

Comment: @LeviRamsey One can implement a lot of things, but this one is not an interface, it's just this thing with two lists ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @LeviRamsey yeah, but I want to write my own class. So could you please say how can I do that with my own class?

Comment: As Andrey said, with what's in that `Queue`, you can't.